# how websites does detect TOR (and not let me in)

Tags: tor

I cannot enter some websites using the TOR or torify navigator

ex: http://pagesjaunes.fr/

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Answer (score 3):

Tor publishes a regularly updated list of exit nodes.

https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=1.1.1.1

Comment: ok.. but what should I do with that list ?

Comment: @yarek Nothing. You asked "how websites does detect TOR". They use that list. It's highly unlikely you'll be able to work around that.